# Corrupted zip file using ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

I'm trying to create a zip file to be able to send multiple files over http.

My issue is that the Zip file that is generated is "corrupted" before and after the file has been send. The issue is i'm not able to find what i did wrong as i'm getting no errors inside the console.

So does someone has an idea file my generated zip file is corrupted ?

This is my code :

```
  OutputStream responseBody = t.getResponseBody();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);


            int counter = 1;
            for (PDDocument doc : documents)
            {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("document" + counter);
                zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                ByteArrayOutputStream docOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                doc.save(docOs);
                docOs.close();
                zos.write(docOs.toByteArray());
                zos.closeEntry();
                zos.finish();
                zos.flush();

                counter++;
            }
            zos.close();
            baos.close();


            responseBody.write(baos.toByteArray());
            responseBody.flush();
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If your goal is to send multiple files and not zip specifically, you could use multipart/form-data, possibly with part-wise compression.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `zos.finish()` from inside the loop as it terminates the ZIP entries, as it is handled by `zos.close()` at end of the stream.

With very large streams you will be better off sending ZIP directly to responseBody bypassing `ByteArrayOutputStream` memory buffer.

If you are still having problems check the content type of the output is set. It might be easier to debug by temporarily writing the byte[] to file to check the ZIP format you are sending with:

```
Files.write(Path.of("temp.zip"), baos.toByteArray());
```

This outline below shows sending a simple ZIP over http (from a servlet, adjust the first 2 lines to appropriate calls for "t"). This may help you check which step of your code causes the corruption if you work back to adding your own document objects inside the loop:

```
// MUST set response content type:
// resp.setContentType("application/zip");
OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream(); // or t.getResponseBody();
try(ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(out))
{
    while (counter-- > 0)
    {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("document" + counter+".txt");
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        zos.write(("This is ZipEntry: "+zipEntry.getName()+"\r\n").getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: even after these modifications the zip is still corrupted @DuncG

Comment: If zos.finish() is inside the loop, then the ZIP will only contain the first entry.

Comment: @MichelMelhem DuncG is absolutely right that you need to get rid of every single ByteArrayOutputStream.  You are choking your program’s performance!  Just wrap the response’s output body in a ZipOutputStream and write directly to that.